# Scale .svg images with different heights to obtain the same width

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I have two vectorial (.svg) images that have the same width but a different height.

**Image1 = 1231x240 and Image2 = 1231x44.**

I try to do this on both images (in css):

```
<img src="images/p/p_s.svg" class="pantallaSup" >
<img src="images/p/p_i.svg" class="pantallaInf" >

.pantallaSup{
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
}

.pantallaInf{
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```

but the Image1 gets a bigger width than the Image2.

And most of times, when you zoom in or zoom out the screen, the difference increases or decreases!!

What am I doing wrong?

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/npk1c3u8/2/

Comment: Can you explain your issue clearly? I had checked your demo it's working fine. Just I added space between in the images. https://jsfiddle.net/npk1c3u8/3/ for demo purpose and I couldn't find any issue if possible can you share the screenshot.

Comment: I expect that the 2 images have the exactly same width when they are shown in the screen, (500px in teh example) but using the last version of Firefox and Chrome the first image has a longest width than the Image2.

Comment: Okay fine, I will check it & let you know.

Comment: Jordi@ I have figured it out width issues in Browsers (Mozilla & Chrome) and I will check it & let you know.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

**Note:** I found the issues in your SVG Images. That's why I have created two new SVG images for demo purpose. I had arranged the images like your demo and I also checked width of both images in different browsers.

Now the width has showing perfect.

**SVG DEMO:**

```css
.maxSize{
 width: 600px;
 background-color:gray;
}
.pantallaSup{
 height: auto;
 width: 500px;
} 
.pantallaInf{
 height: auto;
 width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="maxSize">
    <img src="http://imgh.us/svg-1.svg" class="pantallaSup" >
    <img src="http://imgh.us/svg-2.svg" class="pantallaInf" >
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I expected. I'll try to explayn me better with an image. http://imgh.us/lalala_1.png

Comment: Okay fine, I will check it & let you know.

Comment: @Jordi, I have updated the my answer, once check the demo.